# Modified selection sort that selects the biggest number

Tags: java, arrays, selection, sorting

I am trying to write a modified selection sort that selects the biggest number and place it at the end of a list. I ran into a problem. The code is kind of sorting the list but not perfectly. This is the result after I ran the code: 
                Before selection sort: [2, 8, 7, 1, 3, 5, 9, 4, 6]
After selection sorted: [1, 2, 8, 7, 3, 4, 5, 9, 6]

Here is my code:

```
public static int[] sort(int[] list) {
int i, j, maxNum, maxInde, temp = 0;
    for (i = list.length-1; i >= 0; i--) {
        maxNum = list[i];
        maxInde = i;
        for (j = i; j < list.length; j++) {
            if (list[j] < maxNum) {
                maxNum = list[j];
                maxInde = j;
            }
        }
        if (maxNum < list[i]) {
            temp = list[i];
            list[i] = list[maxInde];
            list[maxInde] = temp;
        }
    }
    return list;
}
```

I don't know where the issue is located.

Comment: If I remember selection sort correctly, doesn't it require an additional array to store the sorted array?

Comment: I am swapping the indexes below so it doesn't need another array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the fixed version:

```
int i, j, maxNum, maxInde, temp = 0;
for (i = list.length-1; i >= 0; i--) {
// you start iterating from the end of the list 
// which means that the elements between i and the end of the list are sorted
    maxNum = list[i];
    maxInde = i;
    for (j = 0; j < i; j++) { 
    // you have to iterate through the nonsorted elements
        if (list[j] > maxNum) {
            maxNum = list[j];
            maxInde = j;
        }
    }
    if (maxNum > list[i]) {
    // if you found an element that is bigger then the current element
    // then it should be set as the current element
        temp = list[i];
        list[i] = list[maxInde];
        list[maxInde] = temp;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The algorithm is conceptually flawed because you scan the array from `n-1` downto `0` and at each iteration select the max element from the subarray `a[n-1,...,i]`. This subarray should always be sorted (and should consist of the `n-i` largest elements of the array) ---this is analogous to the loop invariant of the classical selection sort---and the max element to be inserted in the current position should come from the other subarray, i.e., `a[i,...,0]`.

Also, as mentioned in the comments, there is no need to return the array because the algorithm can just modify it.

Answer (score 0):

public static void sortArray (int [] a) {

```
    //find max value in this array
    for (int i = 0; i < a. length; i++) {
        int max=a[0];
        int index=0;
        for (int j=0; j<a. length-i; j++) {
            if (a[j] >max) {
                max=a[j];
                index=j;
            }
        }
        //change the index
        a[index]=a[a.length-(i+1)];
        a[a.length-(i+1)]=max; //max value change the last element
        
    }
}
public static void main (String args[]) {
    int [] a= {91,13,53,64,48,49,99,35,65,38,62,72};
    System.Out.Println (Arrays.toString (ar));
    sortArray(ar);
    System.Out.Println (Arrays.toString (ar));
}
```

}

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```
public static int[] selectionSortWithMax(int[] items) {
    int size = items.length;
    int maxIndex;
    for (int i = size - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
      maxIndex = i;
      for (int j = i; j >= 0; j--) {
        if (items[maxIndex] < items[j]) {
          maxIndex = j;
        }
      }
      int temp = items[i];
      items[i] = items[maxIndex];
      items[maxIndex] = temp;
    }
    return items;
  }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).